# Erro SSL em Delphi

Tags: mysql, delphi, ssl

Estou recebendo o erro `ssl3_get_record wrong version number` quando seto a propriedade `Connected` do `ADOConnection` para `true`.

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Comment: Pode mostrar a string de conexão?

Comment: é via odbc: `Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=root;Data Source=amp_indice;`

Comment: Esta com cara de ser problema no servidor. Consegue tentar conectar em outro?

Comment: esse erro retorna somente quando testo a conexão por dentro do projeto, se tento concetar via teste do odbc, ele vai normal